# Post request with a JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a route which posts in `/verify/:token`, where `:token` is a jwt, but in my view the form sends a post request to `/verify/:token` and then in my route logic I get a invalid jwt because `:token` is being send, how can I fix this?

```
<form action="/verify/:token" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group form-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <input id="passcode" type="text" class="form-control" name="passcode" placeholder="Pass Code" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block;">Verify</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post you route logic? Is it using Express for routing?

Comment: Yes, express.js

Comment: Did you think about or implement any of these things?
 1. Create an Express Middleware for token handling
 2. Generating the token
 3.  Manage client-side token handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass token to your form page router

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '5m' }).then((token) => {
        res.render("postForm", {
            token: token
        });
  });
});
```

now you can use token in hidden input field assuming you are using ejs in client

```
 <form action="/verify" method="POST">
        <div class="input-group form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
     <input id="token" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="token" value="<%= token %> ">
            <input id="passcode" type="text" class="form-control" name="passcode" placeholder="Pass Code" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block;">Verify</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need ro make my generated jmwt (jssonwebtoken) token expire in 5 minutes? expiresIn = 300 doesn't seem to work

Comment: How are you generating your JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery in the client side, you have to prevent the default action of form when it is submitted. Then you have to send the ajax request by taking the value of the `input` field

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    //prevent default
    e.preventDefault();

    let token = $('#passcode').val();
    let url = "/verify/" + token;
    $.post( url, function( data ) {
        // Do something once the ajax call succeeds
    }).fail(function() {
         alert( "error" );
    });
});
```